# discord.js Как создать приглашение на канал и отправить его в чат

Tags: javascript, discord-api

Здравствуйте, я пишу бота для discord. Прочитал в документации о invite, но так и не смог разобраться как создавать приглашение и отправлять его в чат.

(ссылка на документацию https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)

Я был бы очень рад, если кто-то более опытный показал пример того, как это должно выглядеть...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подходит ? Если да, закрывайте тему.

```
const robot = new Discord.Client();

robot.on("message",(message) => 
{   
    if(message.content == "!inv")
    {
        message.channel.createInvite({temporary : true})
       .then(inv =>message.channel.sendMessage (`https://discord.gg/${inv.code}`));                    
    }
});
```